# No login dialog in Kubuntu after instaling fglrx and reinstallation of xong did not help

Tags: kubuntu, login, radeon

In Kubuntu 13.04 64 bit, `fglrx` did not install, so I tried to reinstall XServer as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
sudo dpkg-reinstall xserver-xorg-core
sudo reboot
```

After that, on boot only a picture with "Kubuntu" appears and freezes, sometimes no reaction to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. Purging and reinstalling xserver-xorg did not help.

Answer (score 0):

No login dialog... So you're saying that you're not able to login anymore as well as access your machine?

Try this command by going into recovery mode:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

I did this on Ubuntu, but since Kubuntu is derived from the original Ubuntu, it certainly should work.

In case the above command doesn't show you any current login managers installed on your computer, then you may need to install one of them. Enter this:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

There is kdm, lightdm, gdm, etc... Just google for 'ubuntu login managers'.

Hope that helped!

Comment: No it didn't. Had to reinstall, luckily my /home is on a separate partition.

Comment: After that I got an idea what the reason might be: "Install additional drivers" sets up fgrlx, but that shows a "Hardware not supported" watermark on the screen. A solution is to install fgrlx-upgrades. Strangely, in the previous installation the driver stopped working (scrolling was very slow), so I tried to reinstall fgrlx and forgot about the upgrades...

Comment: @glebB So after you reinstalled Ubuntu, it's all in working order now? If it isn't maybe, it's a MAYBE, your problem is somehow related to this: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears). If you aren't able to access the terminal, try going into recovery mode and accessing it.